# RStudio keyboard shortcut to run child documents in a knitr doc?

Tags: rstudio

I have a knitr doc.  Actually, many.  I've started factoring out common code in [child documents](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486298-Working-with-Multiple-Rnw-Files).  For example, in a doc `foo.Rnw` I might have:

```
<<setup, child='setup.Rnw'>>=
@
```

When I'm debugging, I run all the chunks from `foo.Rnw` by opening that file and typing option-command-n (on OS X) over and over.  However, it doesn't run the chunks in the child doc, so I have to open the child doc, run option-command-n in that doc, then switch back.  With several child docs, this is a pain.

Is there a simple way to run an entire child doc in interactive mode in RStudio?

[This post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/best-way-to-run-child-markdowns-and-or-bookdown-chapters-interactively-in-rstudio/46495) asks the same thing (I think), and is unresolved.